# Hide a UIButton when another button is tapped

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, hide

How can I hide a `UIButton` on the tap of another button, or any other event?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create an outlet for the button to hide and connect it in your xib:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

Now create an `IBAction` for the other button and connect it in the xib:

```
-(IBAction)hideButton
{
    myButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

So now when you click on the second button, it will hide `myButton`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `IBAction` for the button tap:

```
 [*yourbutton* setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.btnReport setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your other button's tap action:

```
yourButton.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)hideButton
{
       yourbutton.hidden = YES;
}
```

That should do it.